# What was the basis for Crick's proposal of the central dogma of molecular biology?

Tags: biology

In 1957 Crick propounded the central dogma of molecular biology:

> The Central Dogma. This states that once "information" has passed into protein it cannot get out again. In more detail, the transfer of information from nucleic acid to nucleic acid, or from nucleic acid to protein may be possible, but transfer from protein to protein, or from protein to nucleic acid is impossible. Information means here the precise determination of sequence, either of bases in the nucleic acid or of amino acid residues in the protein.

Why is it so important? What was the evidence Crick based his dogma upon?

Comment: If you assume that genetic information is the basis on which an organism works, then it stands to reason that the entire chemistry of an organism should happen with reactions that do not alter the genetic information. For instance, people know their names, what their job is, where they live and with whom, and very rarely they question these pieces of information during their daily routine.

Comment: But people can change their names, their jobs and where they live and with whom. Who says that organisms cant change their DNA?

Comment: @DescheleSchilder - Welcome to the world of Lamarckian Evolution.